# In appcenter failed unit test specifies only function name and line number

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, visual-studio-app-center

Edit, probably the better place to have posted this is on the appcenter forums (which I have now done):
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-cli/issues/1137

In short, an app I'm working on is built in appcenter and set to run unit tests, the problem I have though is that I'm unable to figure out what is making them fail (they won't fail locally).

I can't share the code that I'm having trouble with here, but to illustrate the problem I'm having, Suppose I defined the following kotlin function:

```
fun returnFooString() {
    return "Foo "
}
```

and wrote the following test:

```
@Test
fun test_returnFooString_returns_foo() {
    val foo = returnFooString()
    assertThat("${foo} is equal to "Foo", "Foo", foo)
}
```

What I'd like to see is something like:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Foo  is equal to Foo
    Expected: "Foo"
    but: was "Foo "
Expected :Foo 
Actual   :Foo
```

However the only thing I would see in the appcenter logs for this failing test is:

```
com.mypackage.name.MyTest > test_returnFooString_returns_foo FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at MyTest.kt:4
```

and so I have no clue what just happened. I'm still somewhat of a beginner to android development, and though I've searched google, I haven't been successful in finding something that looks relevant. Is there some setting that can be placed in the build.gradle to not suppress the assertion message, or some environment variable(s) I need to specify in appcenter, or something else to see what was expected and received?

Right now I'm seeing if I can throw exceptions in the test / code to shed some light on the issue but there must be a nicer way (especially since it takes about 10 minutes for a build)

**Edit**: throwing exceptions doesn't work, if I throw an exception logging out every variable I'm interested in, all I get back is something like:

```
com.mypackage.name.MyTest > test_returnFooString_returns_foo FAILED
    java.lang.Exception at MyTest.kt:4
```

At this point it seems I either have to abandon the tests or do something crazy like writing 256 tests to figure out the first character my string has at position 0, then 10 minutes later another 256 to figure out the second ...

Answer (score 1):

I turns out that logging can be enabled with the following:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        testLogging {
            showStandardStreams true
        }
    }
}
```